# SQLPLUS - Trigger that updates values as they are inserted trouble

Tags: sql, triggers

I am trying to create an SQL trigger that will update all values being inserted into a table as they are inserted after the time of the trigger's creation. I can't get this to work. he is my current code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SALARY" 
AFTER INSERT ON "EMP" 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE "EMP" SET SALARY = SALARY + 5000 WHERE EMP_TYPE = 'MANAGER' AND EMP_ID> 200;
END;
/
```

The section `'EMP_ID > 200'` is to ensure that previous records are not being modified. SQLPLUS is creating the trigger, but upon insertion of a new record I am getting a table mutation error.

I have also attempted the following query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SALARY" 
BEFORE INSERT ON "EMP" 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE "EMP" SET :NEW.SALARY = :NEW.SALARY + 5000 WHERE :NEW.EMP_TYPE = 'MANAGER' AND :NEW.EMP_ID> 200;
END;
/
```

This trigger fails to create with an invalid user.table.column error (ORA-07147). Removing the first ':NEW." from the query such that the line becomes:

```
UPDATE "EMP" SET SALARY = :NEW.SALARY + 5000 WHERE :NEW.EMP_TYPE = 'MANAGER' AND ...etc
```

This will allow the trigger to compile, but the value won't update until a new value is inserted into the table, and so on.

How can I get this trigger to work? P.S. I know a trigger might not be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can affect the newly inserted row directly in a **before insert** trigger, by using the `new` keyword:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SALARY" 
BEFORE INSERT ON "EMP" 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (new.emp_type = 'MANAGER')
BEGIN 
    :new.salary = :new.salary + 5000;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly. For anyone who looks at this question in the future remember to place parenthesis around the WHEN statement and I had to change - to :-